# Why multiple processes for Google Chrome in Task Manager while only one process for firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, task-manager

I am using **Windows 7** on my computer.

I use following browsers at a time:

Google Chrome

Mozilla Firefox

Now in my firefox browser, I have webpages running in more than 18 tabs & there is only 1 process for the entire firefox in the Task Manager. And they consume memory around 316004KB.
And I have around 4 tabs opened in Google Chrome with 6 processes in the Task Manager? Why is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You're always going to have at least n + 1 chrome.exe processes, where n is the number of unique domains you have open across all visible tabs. The +1 is for the "Browser" process coordinating everything else. (e.g. I have 5 tabs open, 4 for SuperUser, 1 for another site. I have 2 Tab processes open)
You'll also have processes for any extensions that might have a background window open. (e.g. Adblock Plus, Ghostery, Stylish, NinjaKit all require an extra process)
```

Hit Shift+Esc or go to Chrome's Task Manager (under the Tools menu/sub-menu depending on which version of Chrome you're running) to see a list of all the processes and what they're being used for.